# How to set up a virtual printer and monitor with UniDrv or XPS driver v3 in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, xps, wdk, virtual-printer

I am trying to **create a virtual printer** to capture print outs from applications in my own application.

I have successfully implemented one that uses the Microsoft PostScript driver and produces ps files.  *(A lot of code extracted from different open source projects)*

However, due to licensing issues with GhostScript on production servers, (it is NOT free for business solutions), I want to implement a different **driver that produces XPS files or any other format that I can use to extract text, convert to a PDF, extract images of each page**, etc.

The code that I am using with the postscript driver and **actually works** quite well is as follows:

```
// Declare the AddPrinterDriver as extern.
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool AddPrinterDriver(String pName, UInt32 Level, ref DRIVER_INFO_3 pDriverInfo);

// Create a function to call it.
public void AddPrinterDriver(string driverName, string driverPath, string dataPath, string configPath, string helpPath)
{
    DRIVER_INFO_3 di = new DRIVER_INFO_3();
    di.cVersion = 3;
    di.pName = driverName;
    di.pEnvironment = null;
    di.pDriverPath = driverPath;
    di.pDataFile = dataPath;
    di.pConfigFile = configPath;
    di.pHelpFile = helpPath;
    di.pDependentFiles = "";
    di.pMonitorName = null;
    di.pDefaultDataType = "RAW";

    if (!AddPrinterDriver(null, 3, ref di))
    {
         Exception exc = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
         throw exc;
    }
}
```

Install Printer method (without proper validation and logging):

```
public void InstallVirtualPrinter()
{
    // Declare file names for PostScript printer driver. (Preinstalled in Vista and Up)
    string driverFileName = "PSCRIPT5.DLL";
    string configFileName = "PS5UI.DLL";
    string helpFileName = "PSCRIPT.HLP";
    string dataFileName = "MyCustomConfig.PPD";

    string driverPath = null;
    string dataPath = null;
    string configPath = null;
    string helpPath = null;

    try
    {
        //Set Printer Driver Path and Files.
        string printerDriverPath = Path.Combine(GetPrinterDirectory(), "3");

        // Set the path for the driver files.
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(printerDriverPath))
        {
            driverPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", printerDriverPath, driverFileName);
            dataPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", printerDriverPath, dataFileName);
            configPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", printerDriverPath, configFileName);
            helpPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", printerDriverPath, helpFileName);
        }

        // Add Printer Monitor
        if (!DoesMonitorExist(PrinterMonitorName))
        {
            AddPrinterMonitor(PrinterMonitorName); 
        }

        // Add Printer Port
        if (!DoesPrinterPortExist(PrinterPortName))
        {
            AddPrinterPort(PrinterPortName, PrinterMonitorName);
        }

        // Add Printer Driver
        if (!DoesPrinterDriverExist(PrinterDriverName))
        {
            //
            //
            //
            //
            // This references the above method in this SO question.

            AddPrinterDriver(PrinterDriverName, driverPath, dataPath, configPath, helpPath);
            //
            // This fails when trying with a driver different than PScript.
            //
        }

        // Add Printer
        if (!DoesPrinterExist(PrinterName))
        {
            InstallPrinter(PrinterName, PrinterPortName, PrinterDriverName);
        }

        // Configure Virtual Port
        ConfigureVirtualPort(PrinterMonitorName, PrinterPortName);

        // Restart Spool Service
        RestartSpoolService();

        log.Info("Virtual printer installation completed successfully");
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        log.ErrorFormat("An exception has been raise when attempting to install the printer \n{0}", exc);
    }
}
```

So here is the question:

**How can I use a different driver, like UniDrv or XPS to implement the virtual printer/monitor?**.

I have tried with UniDrv by replacing the following lines in the code above:

```
string driverFileName = "unidrv.dll";
string dataFileName = "sample.GPD";
string configFileName = "unidrvui.dll";
string helpFileName = "unidrv.hlp";
```

When I run the method `AddPrinterDriver` I get an exception indicating `"The system cannot find the file specified"`.

It doesn't say what file is missing.  I assume there may be missing some dependencies, or the sample.GPD file that I found is not good.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont think the driver can be written in C#. You used C++? And how is that you can display the virtual printer among other printers. Is that done by the first function AddPrinterDriver?

Comment: It is written in C and accessed from C#.   I finally ended up with a different driver as this one wasn't really the correct implementation.

Comment: Oh, please describe more. I am also working with a similar situation. I need to chose between unidrv, postscript and xpsdrv. I suppose I would not choose Postscript as it seemed to be very old. And I want to write a virtual printer out of it which should redirect the print data to my application. Your knowledge would really help.

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to do it?

Comment: Hi @agarcian, Did you found what should be used in place of "sample.GPD" ?

Answer (score 1):

Before executing AddPrinterDriver, install all files (unidrv.dll, unidrvui.dll, sample.gpd) in the driver path ie., spool/drivers/x86Orx64 path.